# Updating data point position on a line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm currently using nvd3 to create a simple line chart. The data consists of two series and is creating in the below function:

```
function buildData(xval) {
  var inputtedData = 2; 
  var bindedData = []; 
  var series2 = []; 

  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    bindedData.push({y: inputtedData, x: i}); 
  }

  series2.push({y: inputtedData, x: xval}); 

  return [
  {
    values: bindedData, 
    color: '#4386f4'
  },
  {
    values: series2,
    color: '#000000'
  }
  ];
}
```

`bindedData` forms a straight line and `series2` consists of a single point which will sit at some position on the overall line. The parameter is used to input a new x position for the data series 2 point.

Initially, the graph data is built correctly and the graph is shown perfect. Going a step further, I've added a html button which has an `onClick` event linked to a function which aims to update the data source and parse a new `xval` (in this example I have hard-coded the value as 3):

```
function updateTheChart(){
  console.log('updating....'); 
  var data = buildData(3.4);  
  d3.select('#chart3').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart); 
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
}
```

The desired result is obviously for the data point to visually move to its new x position when the function is fired, but, that is not the case at the moment and I'm a little unsure why.

I won't post all of my code in this question, instead I've made a minimal example which hopefully conforms to the site guidelines. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd11m9c2/).

I hope I've expressed my intentions clearly in this post but please do tell me if I'm missing relevant information.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing the chart and line using `nvd3`.  The point however, you are adding using conventional `d3`.  `nvd3` has no knowledge of it and triggering a re-draw isn't going to do anything.  If you want to update the point, you need to it with just `d3`:

```js
buildGraph();

function buildData(xval) {
  var inputtedData = 2;
  var bindedData = [];
  var series2 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    bindedData.push({
      y: inputtedData,
      x: i
    });
  }

  series2.push({
    y: inputtedData,
    x: xval
  });

  return [{
    values: bindedData,
    color: '#4386f4'
  }, {
    values: series2,
    color: '#000000'
  }];
}

function buildGraph() {
  ckdDeathOutputGraph(buildData(5.5), '#chart3', 'test');
}

var chart;
var chartData;
var points;

function ckdDeathOutputGraph(processedData, location, axisLabel) {

  nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.lineChart()
      .forceX([2.5, 7.5])
      .forceY([0, 3.5])
      .options({
        duration: 300,
        userInteractiveGuideline: true
      });

    chart.xAxis
      .axisLabel('')
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.f'))
      .staggerLabels(true);

    chart.yAxis
      .axisLabel(axisLabel)
      .tickFormat(function(d) {
        if (d == null) {
          return 'N/A';
        }
        return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
      });

    data = processedData;

    chartData = d3.select('body').select(location).append('svg').datum(data);
    chartData.transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    points = d3.select('#chart3 .nv-groups')
      .selectAll("circle.myPoint")
      .data(data[0].values.filter(function(d) {
        return d.y;
      }))
      .enter().append("circle").attr("class", "myPoint")

    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return chart.xAxis.scale()(data[1].values[0].x);
    })

    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return chart.yAxis.scale()(data[1].values[0].y);
      })
      .attr("r", 5)

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart
  });
}

updateTheChart = function() {
  console.log('updating....');
  var data = buildData(3.4);
  
  points
   .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return chart.xAxis.scale()(data[1].values[0].x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return chart.yAxis.scale()(data[1].values[0].y);
    })
    .attr("r", 5);  
  
  //d3.select('#chart3').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart);
  //nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
}
```

```css
/* nvd3 version 1.8.1 (https://github.com/novus/nvd3) 2015-06-15 */

.nvd3 .nv-axis {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .75;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis path.domain {
  stroke-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-x path.domain {
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e5e5e5;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis .zero line,

/*this selector may not be necessary*/

.nvd3 .nv-axis line.zero {
  stroke-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nvd3 .x .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text,
.nvd3 .x2 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text,
.nvd3 .x3 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text {
  text-anchor: middle
}

.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-disabled {
  opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars rect {
  fill-opacity: .75;
  transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars rect.hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars .hover rect {
  fill: lightblue;
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars text {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nvd3 .nv-bars .hover text {
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nvd3 .nv-multibar .nv-groups rect,
.nvd3 .nv-multibarHorizontal .nv-groups rect,
.nvd3 .nv-discretebar .nv-groups rect {
  stroke-opacity: 0;
  transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3 .nv-multibar .nv-groups rect:hover,
.nvd3 .nv-multibarHorizontal .nv-groups rect:hover,
.nvd3 .nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks rect:hover,
.nvd3 .nv-discretebar .nv-groups rect:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-discretebar .nv-groups text,
.nvd3 .nv-multibarHorizontal .nv-groups text {
  font-weight: bold;
  fill: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


/* boxplot CSS */

.nvd3 .nv-boxplot circle {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

.nvd3 .nv-boxplot circle:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-boxplot rect:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 line.nv-boxplot-median {
  stroke: black;
}

.nv-boxplot-tick:hover {
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}


/* bullet */

.nvd3.nv-bullet {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-measure {
  fill-opacity: .8;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-measure:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-marker {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-markerTriangle {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-tick line {
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range.nv-s0 {
  fill: #eee;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range.nv-s1 {
  fill: #ddd;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range.nv-s2 {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-subtitle {
  fill: #999;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range {
  fill: #bababa;
  fill-opacity: .4;
}

.nvd3.nv-bullet .nv-range:hover {
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick {
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.hover {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.positive rect {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.negative rect {
  stroke: #d62728;
  fill: #d62728;
}

.with-transitions .nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick {
  transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-candlestickBar .nv-ticks line {
  stroke: #333;
}

.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-disabled rect {
  /*fill-opacity: 0;*/
}

.nvd3 .nv-check-box .nv-box {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.nvd3 .nv-check-box .nv-check {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

.nvd3 .nv-series.nv-disabled .nv-check-box .nv-check {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-controlsWrap .nv-legend .nv-check-box .nv-check {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* line plus bar */

.nvd3.nv-linePlusBar .nv-bar rect {
  fill-opacity: .75;
}

.nvd3.nv-linePlusBar .nv-bar rect:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3 .nv-groups path.nv-line {
  fill: none;
}

.nvd3 .nv-groups path.nv-area {
  stroke: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-line .nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-scatter.nv-single-point .nv-groups .nv-point {
  fill-opacity: .5 !important;
  stroke-opacity: .5 !important;
}

.with-transitions .nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point {
  transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point.hover,
.nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point.hover {
  stroke-width: 7px;
  fill-opacity: .95 !important;
  stroke-opacity: .95 !important;
}

.nvd3 .nv-point-paths path {
  stroke: #aaa;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
  fill: #eee;
  fill-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3 .nv-indexLine {
  cursor: ew-resize;
}


/********************
 * SVG CSS
 */


/********************
  Default CSS for an svg element nvd3 used
*/

svg.nvd3-svg {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/********************
  Box shadow and border radius styling
*/

.nvtooltip.with-3d-shadow,
.with-3d-shadow .nvtooltip {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nvd3 text {
  font: normal 12px Arial;
}

.nvd3 .title {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
}

.nvd3 .nv-background {
  fill: white;
  fill-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-noData {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/**********
*  Brush
*/

.nv-brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nv-brush .resize path {
  fill: #eee;
  stroke: #666;
}


/**********
*  Legend
*/

.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-series {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nvd3 .nv-legend .nv-disabled circle {
  fill-opacity: 0;
}


/* focus */

.nvd3 .nv-brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: 0 !important;
}

.nvd3 .nv-brushBackground rect {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: .4;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick {
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.hover {
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.positive {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
}

.nvd3.nv-ohlcBar .nv-ticks .nv-tick.negative {
  stroke: #d62728;
}

.nvd3 .background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #EEE;
  stroke-opacity: .4;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3 .nv-parallelCoordinates-brush .extent {
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .6;
  stroke: gray;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.nvd3 .nv-parallelCoordinates .hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.nvd3 .missingValuesline line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 5, 5;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie path {
  stroke-opacity: 0;
  transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-width 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-pie-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  fill: rgba(19, 196, 249, 0.59);
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-slice text {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie path {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .hover path {
  fill-opacity: .7;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-label {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-pie .nv-label rect {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}


/* scatter */

.nvd3 .nv-groups .nv-point.hover {
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.nvd3 .nv-scatter .nv-point.hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
}

.nv-noninteractive {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nv-distx,
.nv-disty {
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* sparkline */

.nvd3.nv-sparkline path {
  fill: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus g.nv-hoverValue {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-hoverValue line {
  stroke: #333;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus,
.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus g {
  pointer-events: all;
}

.nvd3 .nv-hoverArea {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-xValue,
.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-yValue {
  stroke-width: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-yValue {
  stroke: #f66;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-maxValue {
  stroke: #2ca02c;
  fill: #2ca02c;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-minValue {
  stroke: #d62728;
  fill: #d62728;
}

.nvd3.nv-sparklineplus .nv-currentValue {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}


/* stacked area */

.nvd3.nv-stackedarea path.nv-area {
  fill-opacity: .7;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
  transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -moz-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: fill-opacity 250ms linear, stroke-opacity 250ms linear;
}

.nvd3.nv-stackedarea path.nv-area.hover {
  fill-opacity: .9;
}

.nvd3.nv-stackedarea .nv-groups .nv-point {
  stroke-opacity: 0;
  fill-opacity: 0;
}

.nvtooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  z-index: 10000;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  /* MODIFICATION TO MAKE THE TOOLTIP CLICKABLE */
  /*pointer-events: none;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.nvtooltip {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 4px;
}


/*Give tooltips that old fade in transition by
    putting a "with-transitions" class on the container div.
*/

.nvtooltip.with-transitions,
.with-transitions .nvtooltip {
  transition: opacity 50ms linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 50ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 50ms linear;
  transition-delay: 200ms;
  -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.nvtooltip.x-nvtooltip,
.nvtooltip.y-nvtooltip {
  padding: 8px;
}

.nvtooltip h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.75);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.nvtooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nvtooltip span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px 0;
}

.nvtooltip table {
  margin: 6px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.nvtooltip table td {
  padding: 2px 9px 2px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nvtooltip table td.key {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nvtooltip table td.value {
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nvtooltip table tr.highlight td {
  padding: 1px 9px 1px 0;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}

.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nvtooltip table td.legend-color-guide div {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.nvtooltip .footer {
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nvtooltip-pending-removal {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;
}


/****
Interactive Layer
*/

.nvd3 .nv-interactiveGuideLine {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.nvd3 line.nv-guideline {
  stroke: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.js"></script>
<button onClick="updateTheChart()">Update</button>
<div id="chart3"></div>
```